# Host SignalR in IIS

Tags: c#, iis, signalr, signalr-hub

I'm just wondering and it is hunting me for these past few days is it possible to Host a SignalR Hub in IIS? is that event possible? i found a solution called "self hosting" but it is with the help of a console application. i want to host the SignalR Hub in my IIS is that possible? can someone provide me an example regarding this?

im going to post the code for the self Hosting i thought i might help

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // This will *ONLY* bind to localhost, if you want to bind to all addresses
            // use http://*:8080 to bind to all addresses. 
            // See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener.aspx 
            // for more information.
            string url = "http://localhost:8080";
            using (WebApp.Start(url))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Server running on {0}", url);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
    class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
    public class MyHub : Hub
    {
        public void Send(string name, string message)
        {
            Clients.All.addMessage(name, message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: were you able to find a solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hosting SignalR in IIS is as simple as creating a website with a SignalR Hub, and then publishing it to a website within your IIS.

The SignalR Hub will then be located at http://www.yourdomain.com/

If you follow this tutorial here, you will find out what you need http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr

Comment: Should signalR to be published on specific website or it can be hosted on the same url as a WEB API

Comment: Either/Or just depends what you want to do.

Comment: I have created WEB API project and within it implemented Hub and all logic needed for SignalR. Running from VS works fine, but after I hosted on IIS on the server it does not work properly, and there are no exceptions. So, I am wondering if I need create another website which is different from WEB API and there host my SignalR logic.

Comment: I don't understand why this question was marked correct.  The linked tutorial is about self-hosting signalR with owin, so it's not addressing OP's question about how to use signalR in an IIS hosted app.  Simply creating a SignalR hub in an IIS app has no effect.

Comment: The tutorial has everything you need to create a new asp.net project, which can then easily be published and run on IIS. What is the problem you are having?

Comment: @TylerJones I completely agree. I looked at that article twice because I figured I missed the IIS section. That link has NOTHING to do with IIS hosting

Comment: "Hosting SignalR in IIS is as simple as creating a website with a SignalR Hub, and then publishing it to a website within your IIS." @CoderForHire - There is nothing special regarding hosting a website in IIS and hosting a SignalR website in IIS. Just the same.

Comment: @ Tim B James Copying and pasting from their web site doesn't change anything. There is no EXAMPLE of hosting SignalR in IIS. Telling someone it's easy doesn't show you HOW to do it.

Answer (score 10):

Websocket support is not enabled by default on IIS. It was introduced in IIS 8, and has to be enabled from windows' optional features: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-websocket-protocol-support

Optional features -> IIS -> WWW services -> App Dev Features -> Websocket protocol

Disclaimer: I found this after asking a question about this myself, so I copied my answer from there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61411666/4364057

In case somebody finds this after me, I'd like to provide a working answer to the question that I think is better than the accepted one.

Answer (score 0):

The deployment for self hosting signalr server is that run the console exe by admin privilege. 192.168.1.10 is local computer IP. And other devices can connect the url by signalr.

fullIP  = @"http://" + "192.168.1.10" + @":9001"
SignalR = WebApp.Start(fullIP);