# SignalR connection won't start to IIS-hosted app

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis, signalr

I made an application, and am trying to connect to the backend via SignalR.

The ASP.NET Core 3.1 backend is hosted in IIS for easy development.

Calling the StartAsync method on the client successfully negotiates, but then hangs forever on the GET:

```
GET http://localhost:81/signalr?id=W3F2TRVrx_lxZoinHzTzmA
```

The StartAsync() call can't return.

This only happens on IIS. When I start the app self-hosted, it works.

The rest of the WebAPI works on the IIS as well. Just SignalR won't connect.

Any idea why? I found [quite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26418349/host-signalr-in-iis) [a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54262710/xamarin-signalr-hanging-on-connect) [few](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52524572/signalr-pending-start-connection) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60283573/blazor-client-side-signalr-not-working-when-hosting-to-iis) and answers here, but none of them actually solve this precise problem.

Comment: Have you installed IIS webhosting bundle? When you deploy the application from IIS express to IIS, application pool identity also get changed so have you tried to change application pool identity to an account like local sytem? If you need to find the root cause, then you may need to check event log or dump file to find the hang call stack. So we would know what is pending in the thread and what's the problem.

Comment: Where would i find the webhosting bundle? Windows optional features? Or Web PI?

Comment: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.1. When you need to host asp.net core application in in-process model, web hosting bundle is required.

Comment: Can't try it right now as I'm at work, but wouldn't this mean I can't host core31 applications at all? The rest of my application works as expected, the calls to controller methods work perfectly fine.

Comment: So I have that module installed, but same result: Everything works except the SignalR connection.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So I actually found the answer myself:

Websocket support is not enabled by default on IIS. It was introduced in IIS 8, and has to be enabled from windows' optional features: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-websocket-protocol-support

Optional features -> IIS -> WWW services -> App Dev Features -> Websocket protocol

Comment: I enable the websocket protocal so it't was not working, why??, how can U help me, please!

Comment: What exactly is not working? Does it work when self-hosted without IIS?

Comment: services.AddSignalR(), it's work when I run with visual studio 2017, so not working when  I deploy to IIS on  the Window Server 2016

Comment: ...Is the .AddSignalR call itself crashing? Do you have a stacktrace? As this one didn't solve your problem, maybe you should make your own post to further discuss your specific issue.

Comment: How did you deploy your SignalR dotnet project to IIS, same as other dotnet project? and how is your CORS setup?

Comment: Like any other asp.net project indeed. I think even I built this, I had CORS open for everything, but by now I only have localhost or the live URL depending on environment.